# Problems with tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

I would like to do a figure that looks like this (using tikz-feynman):[image]

but it simply won't work. This is the best I can actually do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,french,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{float,physics,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,babel,lmodern,beramono}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{luainputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, vertical=a to b] 
 {{[edges={fermion}]
  l1 -- l2,
  l2 -- l3,
  l3 -- l4,
  l4 -- a,
  a -- r1,
  r2 -- r3,
  r3 -- r4
 },
 {
  r1 -- [ghost] r2,
 },
 { [edges={photon}]
  l2 -- e1,
  l3 -- e2,
  l4 -- e3,
  a -- b,
  r1 -- e4,
  r2 -- e5,
  r3 -- e6
 },
};
\end{feynman} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

and this is not what I want.